# psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, psql

I've been struggling to fix this solution. I've followed multiple guidelines none of them seem to work for me..

So I open PostGres app from my applications folder
It throws following error in the log

```
FATAL:  could not open lock file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied
LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I tried removing the following folder however it says the PGSQL.5432.lock file does not exist. I've done my research and none of them seem to be working for me!
I also tried running psql

```
psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Threw me that error.

Comment: What are the permissions on /tmp? (`ls -l /tmp` will tell you)

Comment: And what user are you trying to run postgresql as?

Comment: @jcaron total 0
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel    0 Nov 28 14:27 .TeamViewer.lock
drwxrwxrwx  4 root  wheel  136 Nov 28 14:27 natinst

Comment: @jcaron I have no idea how I assign user to run postgresql. I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: Sorry, meant `ls -ld /tmp`

Comment: drwx------  4 root  wheel  136 Nov 28 15:21 /tmp

Comment: Your `/tmp` folder has very limited permissions. Only root can read or write into it. This is quite uncommon, `/tmp` is usually quite open.

Comment: @jcaron How do I fix it?

Comment: `chmod 777 /tmp`, running as root.

Comment: @jcaron That seem to not throw that first error. However not being able to run my psql - says following thing psql: FATAL:  role "Ben" does not exist

Comment: You'll need to add user Ben, or to connect using the default `pgsql` user. You'll usually use the latter to do the former. You should check an install guide for your distribution, it'll give you all the details.

Comment: Is there a specific command to log in the user Ben

Comment: Given the message, you're already logged as the user Ben. By default, `psql` will use your Unix username as username for the postgresql connection. You can override that with the `-U` command line switch. Read `man psql` for details.

Answer (score 0):

In `psql` if you didn't specify the user and run `psql` all alone, `psql` will take the current user of your system like :

```
[root@bdd ~]# psql
```

`psql` will take `root` as user.
So you need to tell `psql` which user to log with :

```
[root@bdd ~]# psql -U postgres
```

as you can see `postgres` is the default user if you didn't change it during installation.

If the problem maintain you need to find which port postgresql is using (you might change it during installation )

run :

```
[root@bdd ~]# netstat -tulpn | grep postgres
```

you will find something like this :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5533            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20856/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5533                 :::*                    LISTEN      20856/postgres
```

In my case the port is `5533` so i need to do this :

```
   [root@bdd ~]# psql -U postgres -p 5533
```